# Timer doesn't work when it is created inside a thread with TThread.Syncronize

Tags: multithreading, delphi, timer

I'm trying to create a timer inside a thread using the TThread.Syncronize method, but it apparently doesn't work this way.
For a better understanding, let me expose you the scenario:
My application receives HTTP requests from TIdHttpServer, so I'm already inside a thread at this point, correct?
Then I create an object with a timer using TThread.Syncronize method and stored it in a list of objects that was created in main thread.
I can't understand why the timer doesn't work.
See below a sample code to illustrate the problem:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
  procedure
  begin

    TThread.Synchronize(nil,
    procedure
    begin

      FTimer := TTimer.Create(nil);
      FTimer.OnTimer := HandleOnTimer;

    end);

  end);

end;
```

FTimer is declared in private section of TForm1.

Comment: What does not work? Is there an exception? Or is the OnTimer event just not executed?

Comment: It just is not executed.

Comment: Your original question is answered already. Your edit asks a different question, please ask it separately.

Comment: FYI, in 10.2 Tokyo and later, this code can be simplied using [`TThread.ForceQueue()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.ForceQueue) instead: `procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject); begin TThread.ForceQueue(nil, procedure begin FTimer := TTimer.Create(nil); FTimer.OnTimer := HandleOnTimer; end); end;` No worker thread needed.

Answer (score 3):

[`TThread.CreateAnonymousThread()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.CreateAnonymousThread) creates a thread, but does not execute it. You need to start the created thread manually.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
  procedure
  begin

    TThread.Synchronize(nil,
    procedure
    begin

      FTimer := TTimer.Create(nil);
      FTimer.OnTimer := HandleOnTimer;

    end);

  end).Start();

end;
```

---

Regarding inside a Windows Service:

The `Thread.Synchronize` method executes the passed function in the context of the main thread. There is no main thread by default in a Windows Service application.

Why do you not simply wait the requested amount of time in the thread that you create anyway?

```
TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
  procedure
  begin
    TThread.Sleep(1000);
    HandleOnTimer();
  end).Start();
```

if you are worried about too many threads being created at the same time, use one dedicated thread that executes code based on a timed event queue.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I forgot to call Start() method. Really this piece of code is working, but I can't put it to work in my application... Do you have any idea if I can have problems working this way working with threads coming from TIdHTTPServer?

Comment: Try to create an [mcve]. What kind of application is this? Timer will not work when the application has no message queue. (Like for example it will not work in a console application). it will also not work when the message queue in the UI thread is blocked for some reason.

Comment: It is an Windows Service. I just created an Windows service project and it is not working. I updated the question with a new piece of code that is not working.

Comment: Don't use GUI timers in a service

Comment: "*There is no main thread by default in a Windows Service application.*" - yes, there is. And in a standard `TService` app, there is even a message loop in the main thread. So `TTimer` *can* work in a service, it is just *not advisable* to do so because it is very easy to misuse it (`OnTimer` running in a different thread than the `TService`), and there are better options available anyway (waitable timers, for example).